Istio authentication is blocking access to the application
I have a configuration which is:
AGW(path based routing) --> ingress-gateway in namespace --> virtualservice routing --> service --> pod
My gateway is:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: myapp-ingressgateway
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    istio: myapp-ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - '*'
    port:
      name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt

My virtualservice configuration is:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: myapp-ingress-api
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  gateways:
  - myapp-ingressgateway
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /myapp/api/
    route:
    - destination:
        host: myapp-api
        port:
          number: 80
    timeout: 300s
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /myapp/api/swagger
    route:
    - destination:
        host: myapp-api
        port:
          number: 80
    timeout: 300s

When I try to access my application through web, I can see in ingress logs that the traffic is routed to the right service:
[2024-07-31T11:24:40.680Z] "GET /myapp/api/
HTTP/1.1" 401 - via_upstream - "-" 0 0 7 - "4.234.105.139, 10.122.1.85:37460,10.111.212.48" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/127.0.0.0" "a2705e5b-d656-45c6-b460-f22efbea2ed0" "dev.org.com" "172.0.0.201:8080" outbound|80||
myapp-api.myapp.svc.cluster.local
172.0.0.206:56840 172.0.0.206:8443 10.111.212.48:2851 dev.org.com -

But the connection never reaches the application pod. There is no logging for anything on the application pod.
Somewhere it is getting blocked. I can see that there is a bearer token being passed
$  curl -I -X GET https://dev.org.com/myapp/api/swagger/index.html
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Thu, 01 Aug 2024 05:31:50 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
www-authenticate: Bearer
request-context: appId=cid-v1:f1aff90d-ee54-470b-8bc2-9361f3b3bf52
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
content-security-policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN

Can someone please help me out what might be blocking this?
Thanks
Tried using different routing prefixes and all. But it does not work. Also similar type of virtualservices are already there in the same namespace with different prefixes for other api pods and it works fine

Can you check whether any authorization policies in place would be impacting this?
another way I'd test this is to remove the ingress gateway from the scenario -- for example, create a test pod inside the cluster and send a request directly to myapp-api and see if that goes through. That might tell you if the issue is at the GW or service.
